# SciKit-learn grid search own scoring object syntax

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

I want to search hyper-parameters in a convolutional net built with Keras. For this I am using the KerasClassifier and GridSearchCV from SciKit-learn in line with a good intro that is given here [MachineLearningMastery](http://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/).
Typically SciKit-learn optimizes on `'accuracy'`, however my network runs image segmentation optimizing the Jaccard index. So I need to define my own scoring object for the grid search using make_scorer as explaned here [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) and here [defining your scoring strategy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html). The code section below shows my implementation, but I am getting an error in `model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=eval_loss, metrics=(['eval_func'])`, where I do not know what to specify in metrics. Default is `'accuracy'` but I would assume in my case this would be `'eval_func'` (which works when not doing grid search) or `'score'` but neither of these works in this case.

What is the right syntax?

```
def eval_func(y_true, y_pred):
    '''Evaluation function dice or jaccard, set with global var JACCARD=True'''
    if JACCARD:
        return jaccard_index(y_true, y_pred)
    else:
        return dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)


def get_unet(batch_size=32, decay=0, dropout_rate=0.5, weight_constraint=0):
    '''Create u-net model'''
    dim = 32    

    inputs = Input((3, image_cols, image_rows)) # modified to take 3 color channel input
    conv1 = Convolution2D(dim, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', W_constraint=weight_constraint)(inputs)
    conv1 = Convolution2D(dim, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', W_constraint=weight_constraint)(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    pool1 = Dropout(dropout_rate)(pool1) # dropout added to all layers

    ... more layers ...

    conv10 = Convolution2D(1, 1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(input=inputs, output=conv10)

    optimizer = Adam(lr=LR, decay=decay)   
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=eval_loss, metrics=(['eval_func'])

    return model

def run_grid_search():
    '''Optimize model parameters with grid search'''

    ... loading data ...

    model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_unet, verbose=1, nb_epoch=NUM_EPOCH, shuffle=True)
    # define grid search parameters
    batch_size = [16, 32, 48]
    decay = [0, 0.002, 0.004]
    param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, decay=decay)

    # create scoring object
    score = make_scorer(eval_func, greater_is_better=True)

    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=score, n_jobs=1, verbose=1)
    grid_result = grid.fit(X_aug, Y_aug)
```

Here is the last part of the error I am getting both using 'eval_func' and 'score':

> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py", line 216 , in get
>       return get_from_module(identifier, globals(), 'metric')   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.p y", line
>   16, in get_from_module
>       str(identifier)) Exception: Invalid metric: eval_func

Answer (score 1):

You should unquote it when passing to compile. Keras recognizes metrics in quotation marks only if they're part of the Keras API. See [Keras.io/metrics](https://keras.io/metrics/).

This is the problem:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=eval_loss, metrics=(['eval_func'])
```

You should fix it to:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=eval_loss, metrics=([eval_func])
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20837684)

Comment: It does answer it because he passed the callback function in quotation marks to the compile method rather than without which should fix it.

Comment: I think you'll need to demonstrate your solution, showing specifically what needs to be done. As it stands it is not a real answer just a comment/hint.

Answer (score 0):

By default scikit-learn uses the score function in the estimator, if it exists at all. So you could just override [the score function](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L264) in `KerasClassifier`.

```
class MyEstimator(KerasClassifier):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyEstimator, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def score(self, X, y):
        y_pred = self.predict(X)
        return eval_func(y, y_pred)
```